# In NearProtocol, how to migrate contract state

Tags: nearprotocol, near-sdk-rs

Assume there's a contract written in near-sdk-rs, deployed, has state defined as:

```
#[near_bindgen]
#[derive(BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize)]
pub struct NFT {
    pub tokens: UnorderedMap<TokenId, Token>,
}

#[derive(BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize)]
pub struct Token {
   pub owner: AccountId
}
```

Now there're some usage of this contract, as a result some records of `tokens` stored on chain.
Then I'd like to update this contract by adding a field to `Token`:

```
pub struct Token {
   pub owner: AccountId
   pub name: String // For existing ones, this will be set to ""
}
```

How to do this with existing state kept (similar of doing a database migration)?

Answer (score 6):

You can also see how some of the examples we've created use versioning.

See BerryClub:

```rs
#[derive(BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize)]
pub struct AccountVersionAvocado {
    pub account_id: AccountId,
    pub account_index: AccountIndex,
    pub balance: u128,
    pub num_pixels: u32,
    pub claim_timestamp: u64,
}

impl From<AccountVersionAvocado> for Account {
    fn from(account: AccountVersionAvocado) -> Self {
        Self {
            account_id: account.account_id,
            account_index: account.account_index,
            balances: vec![account.balance, 0],
            num_pixels: account.num_pixels,
            claim_timestamp: account.claim_timestamp,
            farming_preference: Berry::Avocado,
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/evgenykuzyakov/berryclub/blob/ad2b37045b14fa72181ab92831fb741a7c40234b/contract-rs/pixel-board/src/account.rs#L19-L39

There are others but will have to come back to this once I find them

Comment: Good example, to make this example more complete there's also this in berryclub:
```
/// in the contract's struct:
pub legacy_accounts: Vector<AccountVersionAvocado>,
pub accounts: LookupMap<u32, UpgradableAccount>,
```
so you save both version of accounts in contracts and handle both in code

Comment: Also this one from SputnikDAO v2 https://github.com/near-daos/sputnik-dao-contract/blob/d1798679f1520fb9b250fb824a77b08271d191f0/sputnikdao2/src/lib.rs#L54

Answer (score 4):

So far I can only suggest to deploy a temporary contract with old `Token` struct kept as is, and `NewToken` implement `NewToken::from_token`, and a change method:

```rust
impl Token {
    pub fn migrate(&mut self) {
        near_sdk::env::storage_write(
            "STATE",
            NewToken::from_token(self).try_into_vec().unwrap()
        );
    }
}
```

After you migrate the state, you can deploy a contract with the `NewToken` instead of `Token`.

Comment: This is more close to the idea of migration. However if state has grown very big, would it be over block gas limit to call `migrate`?

Comment: With large state one possible solution is to run the migration in chunks.